# Eloquent получить все материалы по значению pivot-таблицы

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Laravel 5

Есть три таблицы в БД c полями:

category:id

category_catalog:catalog_id,category_id

catalog

Данные из таблицы catalog(товары) связаны с разделами (category) через промежуточную таблицу (category_catalog)

Чтобы получить товары из конкретного раздела проблем нет:

```
    class Category extends Model
    public function get_tovars()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Catalog', 'category_catalog', 'category_id', 'catalog_id')->orderBy('position', 'DESC');
}
```

Достаем так:

```
   Category::find(1)->with('get_tovars)->get();
```

А как получить все товары с конретным id раздела, чтобы так:

```
Catalog::where('category', $id)
```

Как прописать связь в модели Catalog?

Comment: Не поняла что вам нужно. "получить товары из конкретного раздела проблем нет", "как получить все товары с конретным id раздела". Товары с id раздела != Товары из раздела?

Comment: Прошу прощения за невнятный вопрос. Мне требовалось получить товары без использования with (для пагинатора). Затупил, ибо ответ: Category::find($id)->get_tovars()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете найти каталог к которому присвоены все товары, и который присвоен под данную категорию.
Пример:
`Category::find($id)->catalog->tovars`
Найти данную категорию, получить каталог к которой она приписана а после получить все товары данного каталога.
Настройте обратные связи для каждой таблицы.

Например:

- Catalog - hasOne Category и hasMany Tovar;
- Category - belongsTo Catalog;
- Tovar - belongsTo Catalog;